# Global keylogger on Mac OS X Mojave using Qt/Accessibility API

Tags: macos, qt

I was wondering if there was a well documented API that could provide a way to process global key and mouse events using the accessibility API. I suspect that there's a class or interface, but I don't know the name, nor do I know where to find the documentation.

My search has brought me to the Carbon Event Taps, which are deprecated:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_event_services

I was wondering if there was a more up-to date API that standardised access to global input events. Specifically I'm looking for something akin to Karabiner Elements' [Event viewer](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/tree/master/src/apps/EventViewer). But that's in Objective C, so not suitable for Qt.

Comment: First it's **Quartz** Event Taps, not Carbon. And what makes you think they're deprecated? They're not and they're the correct technology for this. (If you were using Objective-C or Swift and only need to observe events, not change them, you might be able to use a global event monitor.)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "If you were using Objective-C or Swift and only need to observe events, not change them, you might be able to use a global event monitor." 

There's a different Technology for Objective C, and Swift, but for Qt event taps are fine?

Comment: Cocoa has [`+[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchin), but it requires using Objective-C or Swift. Also, it can only observe events, it can't change them before they are delivered. Event taps can change them, although Mojave put additional restrictions on that.